Time's Square: A New Years Puzzle

Transcription of text:
Since 2025 = 45², it's the year of the square!
What features of squares will help you make your New Year's resolutions?

CIGAR
EGGS
EMILY
HOOK
KILOS
PG
RIGHTMOST
SNOOP
TITLE
UNFIX


The feature of

 FORESIGHTS "four sides".

The 10 squares are...

 Semaphore representation of NXIU = UNFIX -F


 Periodic table elements NOPS = SNOOP -O


 Pigpen letters IGCA = CIGAR -R


 Tetrominos ITTL = TITLE -E


 Five-bit encoding GEG = EGGS -S


 Moon type EMLY = EMILY -I


 Maritime flag P = PG -G


 Morse code OKO = HOOK -H


 Playfair square GH I/J MORST = RIGHTMOST -T


 QWERTY keyboard IOKL = KILOS -S

